# new comments model causing activeadmin view issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My new comments model works well on the website, but there is an issue with activeadmin because when I go to my admin view and try to view 'guidelines' (another model), I get an error message:

> undefined method `comment' for

My model comment.rb:

```
belongs_to :guideline
belongs_to :commenter, class_name: 'User'
attr_accessible :body, :commenter_id
```

My model guideline.rb:

```
attr_accessible :content, :hospital, :title, :user_id, :guideline_id, :specialty, :updated_by, :current_user, :subtitle, :slug, :activities, :comment, :visible
belongs_to :user
has_many :favourite_guidelines
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
```

admin/guidelines.rb:

```
index do                              
  column :comment     
  default_actions                   
end
```

Comment: `undefined method 'comment' for` -- is that the whole error message?

Answer (score 0):

You get an undefined method error because your guideline model has_many comments and therefore has the method `.comments` but not `.comment`. If you are trying to show the number of comments a guideline has then you can do this.

```
column "Comments" do |guideline|
  guideline.comments.count
end
```

If you want to show all the actual comments listed out you can collect whatever the column is in the comment object that holds the text and join them with a comma or newline etc.

```
column "Comments" do |guideline|
  guideline.comments.collect(&:text_form_of_comment).join(",")
end
```

[HERE](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html) is more info on how you can customize you ActiveAdmin index tables.